# Generating enemies while countdown is running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to create a game during a gamejam using HTML CSS Javascript and jQuery.

I have a countdown that shows to the player how many time he has left, and that loses 2 seconds when the main character is getting hit by the enemies.

What I'd like to do is to find a way to generate enemies every x seconds as long as the timer hasn't reached 30s (where he wins) or 0s (where he loses)

I used two libraries so far, QuintusJS [(link here)](http://www.html5quintus.com/) for the physic and jchavannes's countdown [(link here)](http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo), trying to make them work together.
So far, everything has been great, but I can't manage to make a jQuery loop that would look like the following,

```
while(currentTime < 30000){ //30s in milliseconds
    stage.insert(new Q.Enemy({ x: 700, y: 0 })); //Allows ennemies to be generated by QuintusJS
    //TODO : adding a delay between enemies generation
}
```

Because the canvas that Quintus creates becomes totally blank. I also tried to create a function that sets `checkCurrentTime` to `true` while `currentTime` isn't equal to `0`, but changes it to `false` when it's the case, but it still doesn't work.

Am I doing this wrong? If so, how can I manage to have a loop that generates enemies properly?

Comment: `30000s` is an invalid value.

Comment: I don't know if you misspelled or not, but just in case, I have to point that you have a 's' next to the millisenconds and you shouldn't. Do you have any errors on the console?

Comment: Sorry, i rewrited by hand the code I tried, there were no 's' for the value (i will edit my question)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a looper that does something every N milliseconds. For example:

```
var looper = function (delay, callImmediately, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (callImmediately) {
        callback.call(self);
    }
    var iv = setInterval(function () {
        if (deferred.state() === "resolved" || deferred.state() === "rejected") {
            clearInterval(iv);
        } else {
            callback.call(self);
        }
    }, delay);
    return deferred;
};
```

You can then start and stop it whenever you like:

```
// Every second add a new enemy
var loop = looper(1000, false, function () {
    console.log("Adding an enemy");
    //stage.insert(new Q.Enemy({ x: 700, y: 0 }));
});
// Handle done and fail
loop.done(function () { console.log("All enemies were added!"); });
loop.fail(function () { console.log("The loop was stopped before all enemies were added!"); });

// Resolve the looper after 30 seconds (calls .done())
setTimeout(loop.resolve, 30000);
// Or if something went wrong you can also reject it (calls .fail())...
setTimeout(loop.reject, 5000);
```

Here is a small example:

```
var player = {
    health: 100,
};
// Damage the player every second
var iv = setInterval(function () {
    player.health -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (player.health <= 0) {
        clearInterval(iv);
    }
}, 1000);
// Every second add a new enemy
var loop = looper(1000, false, function () {
    if (player.health <= 0) {
        loop.reject("The player is dead. Stopping.");
    } else {
        //stage.insert(new Q.Enemy({ x: 700, y: 0 }));
        console.log("Inserting an enemy; health is", player.health);
    }
});
loop.done(function () { console.log("All enemies were added, and player is still alive!"); });
loop.fail(function (message) { console.log(message) });

// Stop the looper after 30 seconds
setTimeout(loop.resolve, 30000);
```